# Cant generate existing folder for zip (JSZip.js)

Tags: jquery, jszip

**Case 1:**
I am trying to access the existing folder for zip operation, but it can't be generate it. I have tried the below code for zipping existing folder.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.folder("../Download/Themes");
zip.generate();
```

Example:
I have a folder(Themes) with files  which i want to be zip in my application.

- folder - Themes

  - file - css1
  - file - css2

Is it possible to generate zip file from existing folder?

**Case 2:**
After generating a zip file can i get the zip file from its physical path in my application?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add file and its content to your JSZip instance manually according to the JSZip document. So if you want to add the existing folder into a zip file, you need to traversal the folder and add each file like this:

```
zip.file(filename, content);
```

In your case, you should create it as follows:

```
zip.file("Themes/css1",fs.readFileSync('css1'));
zip.file("Themes/css2",fs.readFileSync('css2'));
var content = zip.generate({type:"nodebuffer"});
fs.writeFile("Themes.zip", content, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

> zip.folder("sub") only create or switches to the sub folder of your zip instance, you should put content yourself and then save to physical folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use get function in jquery

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
jQuery.get('Themes/css1.css', function(data) {

        zip.add("Themes/css1.css",data);
        var content = zip.generate({type:"nodebuffer"});
     
        zip.add("hello1.html", bt);
    content = zip.generate();
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
        
}, 'text');
```